# how to add a remove coupon button to commerce checkout page

Tags: commerce

I assumed this would be included in the module, but as far as i can see it isn't. Im using the latest versions of [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), Rules, and [Commerce Coupon](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon).

I want a "remove" button next to the added coupons in case someone wants to remove it and try another one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to recreate your issue. 'Remove' button was available next to the applied coupon.

[image]

The version of coupon code, I'm using is 7.x-2.0-rc2.

The steps I took were:

1. Added a discount and associated a coupon code with it.
2. Added an item to cart and checked out.
3. After confirming checkout was given option to add coupon code.

Checkout settings:
[image]

**Note:**

> The problem could be with checkout page. You can use `order_coupon_list`
>   view block below the coupon code apply form.

Comment: hmmm interesting. looks like you are using Kickstart 2. Wonder if they've added extra coding to that theme? or my theme has hidden it somehow? I've attached screenshots to my original post.

Comment: let me check with other themes.

Comment: hi checked with bartik, seven and omega theme, it was available on all of them.

Comment: checked with devel_themer and found that the block table of applied coupons comes from views: order_coupon_list.